# Declaration and Definition of variables in c

Tags: c, static, initialization, declaration, extern

I understand the terms declaration and definition as below.

**Declaration:** This is just a heads up to the compiler that a variable of specified **"name"** and **"type"** exists in the code. So that it can be defined/assigned at later point of time

**Definition:** This is the process where an instance of the type is created by allocating a suitable space of memory.

```
int var; //Declaration and Definition-Agreed!!!
extern int var; //Declaration only ?
static int var; //Declaration only ?
```

My mind refuses to agree the second and third ones as **declaration only** statements. Because in many references I see, **"extern and static  variables are automatically initialized to zero upon memory allocation"**. And as you see in following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   static int i;
   printf("%d\n",i);
   return 0;
}
```

The output is 0. So Here it looks like the **static int i;** is declaration,definition and auto initialization statement. So please add your justification for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects with static storage duration are initialized by zero in C.

```
static int a; // initialized by zero
int b;        // file-scope, static storage duration, initialized by zero

int main(void)
{
     int c;        // automatic storage duration, indeterminate value
     static int d; // initialized by zero
}
```

`a`, `c` and `d` are declarations and definitions of objects.

`b` is a declaration and a definition because there is no other file-scope occurrence of `b` until the end of the translation unit. Before the end of the translation unit, the declaration is a *tentative* definition.

Answer (score 1):

Just did a experiment and got clarified.

```
static int i; //Declaration,Definition and Auto initialized as zero.
extern int i; //Declaration only. Will throw an error if not externally defined. 
int i; //This when declared outside any code block will be extern by default and initialised to zero
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this example clears your doubt for extern:

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int foo;
int main(){
foo=1;
return 0;
}
```

This code gives you an error because of trying to allocate a value to the location/memory that has not been allocated yet.
Now consider this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int foo = 10;
int main(){
foo=11;
return 0;
}
```

This code compiles correctly as C exhibits some sort of curious behavior in it.

Comment: Welcome and I hope you have got your answer.